# 100% wide element does not stretch more than the viewport width

Tags: html, css

So basically when I shrink the page to say 1000px wide, enough for the x-axis scrollbar to appear. When I scroll to the right the navbar stops filling the 100% width, rather just the viewable width when you shrink the window.

I have had a fiddle around and cannot work out why it is doing this.

Here is the page:
http://astrodeer.com.au/habbonauts/test/index.php

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% of the width is 100% of the width of the parent (which is the screen size). You can scroll to the right, because the header is wider than that, but the bar still won't fill that width.

The easiest fix, without modifying the HTML, is adding this style to your CSS. Doing so will make the nav-bar background at least 1180px, which is the same size as the header.

```
.nav-bar {
  min-width: 1180px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can put the nav-bar inside the header, so it will grow to 100% of the header width.

Answer (score 1):

Add this style, it works fine.

```
body{ float:left; min-width:100%;}
```

**or**

```
body{ display:inline-block; min-width:100%;}
```

*Body will not automatically stretch to 100%;* so we add these.